# Cannot able to see the issues in Sentry dashboard

Tags: sentry, cartalyst-sentry, apache-sentry

I have integrated Sentry with my java project by mentioning the sentry dependency and the plugin details in the main `pom.xml`.

I have included sentry application URL and access token in the *properties* file.

The building is going fine but I still can't see the issue details in the Sentry dashboard.

The main `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
    <artifactId>sentry-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
    <artifactId>sentry-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
    <artifactId>sentry-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>

    <configuration>
        <debugSentryCli>true</debugSentryCli>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <skipSourceBundle>false</skipSourceBundle>
        <skipAutoInstall>false</skipAutoInstall>
        <dsn>http://dns-url</dsn>
        <org>your_organization_slug</org>
        <authToken>your_auth_token</authToken>

        <!-- Configure includes and excludes to scan all files -->
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.java</include>
        </includes>

        <!-- Optionally, you can exclude specific files or directories -->
        <!-- <excludes>
            <exclude>path/to/exclude</exclude>
        </excludes> -->
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>uploadSourceBundle</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

`sentry.properties`:

```
# Sentry DSN (replace with your actual DSN)
dsn=http://dns-url

# Sentry Auth Token (replace with your actual auth token)
authToken=your_auth_token

# Sentry Organization Slug (replace with your organization's slug)
org=your_organization_slug
```

I am getting the below exception in the console output:

```
using this in pom.xml but after running the build using mvn clean install build went success but sentry is not capturing any issues related to this repo but in console am able to see this 

WARN    2024-03-25 11:43:09.152728153 +05:30 Source uploads are not supported by the configured Sentry server
```